# Pasar variables a Querry PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

He estado lidiando ya varios días con este problema, sucede que tengo 2 paginas en Php, en una de ellas declaro la variable "A" para que en la segunda pagina mi filtre por tipo"A" en mi query, sencillamente no lo hace. aquí el primer fragmento de código donde declaro la variable.

```php
<?php
    $title ="Sistema";
    $tipo=$_GET['A'];
    include "head.php";
    include "sidebar2.php";
?>
```

Aquí mi código que lo recibe pero no me filtra por tipo, cabe mencionar que el usuario lo filtra sin problemas, pero no logro filtrar por tipo.

```php
$id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
                $tipo;
                $query_session=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from ticket where user_id=$id and tipo={$tipo}");



                        while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query_session)) {
                            $id=$r['id'];
                            $created_at=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($r['created_at']));
                            $description=$r['description'];
                            $title=$r['title'];
                            $project_id=$r['project_id'];
                            $priority_id=$r['priority_id'];
                            $status_id=$r['status_id'];
                            $kind_id=$r['kind_id'];
                            $category_id=$r['category_id'];
                            $tipo=$r['tipo'];
```

El objetivo es que el sistema me filtre por usuario y tipo de ticket, solo logro filtrar por usuario a través del $id, pero no por $tipo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no metes (o buscas, si estuviera) el tipo en la variable de sesión?

Comment: ¿Obtienes un error? ¿La columna `tipo` es numérica? ¿Haces alguna validación al obtener el tipo?

Comment: La columna "tipo" es VARCHAR, lo estoy manejando por letras, tales como "A,B,C ..etc." Y como lo hariamos por variable sesion si cada pagina de PHP la quiero filtrar php1-=A, php2=B, php3=C, por eso al inicio de cada pagina estoy colocando la variable con su valor $tipo ='A'; y asi en acda pagina.

Comment: Todavía no logro entender cómo se relacionan los dos archivos de los dos bloques de código que compartes. Viendo que usas variables de sesión en el segundo bloque, puedes hacer algo así **en el primer bloque**: `$_SESSION['tipo']=$_GET['A'];`, entonces tendrás el valor del tipo en la variable de sesión, pudiendo recuperarla así: `$tipo=$_SESSION['tipo'];` De todos modos, hay muchas cosas que no quedan claras en tu pregunta, como el hecho mismo de tener que usar dos archivos o todo lo que explicas en el comentario anterior sobre tantas páginas distintas, ¿no has pensado en centralizar?

Comment: Aparte de los comentarios anteriores, si la columna `tipo` no es numérica, deberías encerrar el valor entre comillas: `"SELECT * from ticket where user_id=$id and tipo='{$tipo}'"`

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es que necesitas concatenar en la consulta correctamente.

```
$query_session=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from ticket where user_id=".$id." and tipo=".$tipo);
```

de esa manera tendra que funcionar la consulta bien, en caso de error te aconsejo que pongas las tablas de SQL y mas especificaciones de lo que quieres hacer y como tienes estructurado tu codigo para saber mejor el flujo de informacion.

Espero te sirva saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No funciono amigo, cabe mencionar que si declaro la variable en el querry que deseo filtrar si lo hace, no se por que la variable que estoy pasando por la pagina de php no la imprime, ya probe colocando en la pagina

Y si nme imprime la letra A dentro de la pagina ticketsA.php, PERO NO LOGRO PASARLA AL OTRO ARCHIVO DE CONSULTA, si lo hago directo el filtro, si lo hace.

$query_session=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from ticket where user_id=$id and tipo='A'");

pero lo que yo busco es que dentro de cada pagina exista un filtro por A, B,C,D,E y de esta manera me filtre los tickets por nivel y usuario.

Comment: En el segundo archivo tienes un `$tipo;` casi al principio, que no hace nada, pero que está definiendo de nuevo esa variable. Puede ser que no deje así llegar el valor de ese campo. De todas formas, puedes depurar la consulta asignándoles en otra variable y mostrándola cómo queda. Mira a ver si te muestra la consulta completa o te da error de MySQL.

Comment: No amigo, no arroja la consulta, simp,emente no arroja nada, quedo asi    ````  $id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
                $query_session=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from ticket where user_id=$id and tipo=$tipo");  ````

Comment: Entonces añade al final de tu instrucción mysqli_query un ` or die (mysqli_error($con));` para que te muestre el último error de MySQL. Tiene toda la pinta de que ese valor $tipo se anula en esa línea vacia